# Form Value of drop down category + Translation of 'show option none'

Tags: categories, dropdown, select

I am building a form where a user can submit an article from the front end..

So far so good...
To this form i am doing some submission check using javascript..

When i get to check if a category is choosen

This is the line the retrives categories in the form:

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=---------------->&taxonomy=category&hide_empty=0&name=cats[]&orderby=name&hierarchical=1'); ?>
```

I dont know how to check it.. what is the value being sent to wordpress?
Also..
Can i change this:

```
show_option_none=---------------->
```

into somthing i can translate using the regular tranlation method aka __() or _e()??

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... as thing go when your trying to solve somethimg you have no peace until its fixed so.. i went ahead and did some clear mind thinking (after a night sleep) and got that i can check the HTML for the values returen.

**Just wanted to share incase anyone stumbles with the need for this info**

This:`<?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=---------------->&taxonomy=category&hide_empty=0&name=cats[]&orderby=name&hierarchical=1'); ?>`

Returns a value of the category number for each select item which is easy to check.

Also.. about the translation part
this is the right way to do that..

```
<?php 
$choosecatmsg = __('Choose A Category', 'blue_article_demon');                      
wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none='.$choosecatmsg.'&taxonomy=category&hide_empty=0&name=cats[]&orderby=name&hierarchical=1');
?>
```

Thanks for anyone who took a look 
while i was stuck :)